# Mostrar parte de un iframe de forma correcta en una página que no esté dentro del mismo dominio

Tags: html, css, iframe

mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo poder mostrar parte de un iframe en una página que no esté en el mismo dominio? Básicamente es un iframe al cuál le he disminuido los margenes y lo he colocado dentro un div con position fixed para que pueda hacer el efecto de sólo mostrar la posición que deseo.

El código que estoy utilizando es:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 78px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow:hidden;
} 

 div#content {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 25px;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white: ;
}
div#content iframe {
    display:block;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    position: absolute;
    /*pointer-events:none;*/
    width : 500px;
    height : 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <iframe src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/cuotas" name="frame2" id="frame2" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowtransparency="false"></iframe>
</div>
```

Como se puede ver en el código que he agregado... hay un comportamiento extraño cuando hago click dentro del body del html, es como si el iframe se desbordara. Si quito el height del iframe ya no se muestra toda la parte que deseo que es la parte de los logos de los bancos.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.
Saludos.